# Complex Integration $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\exp(-a(x + id)^2)}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\exp(-a(x + id)^2)}dx
$$
where $x$ and $d$ are real and $i$ is the imaginary unity. 
I tried substituting $x + id$ by $\theta$ but that just gives $\sqrt{\pi}$. I think the solution to this integral will surely have an imaginary component.

Comment: It gives $\sqrt{\pi/a}$ (if $a>0$ of course), not $\sqrt\pi$.

Comment: Consider the contour integral of $e^{-z^2}$ over $\partial\{[-R,R]\times [0,d]\}$, the vertical parts tend to zero as $R\to \infty$, thus the integral is the same as $d=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a>0$. Consider
$$
F(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp\big(-a(x+z)^2\big)\;dx,\qquad z \in \mathbb C
$$
For all $z \in \mathbb C$, the integral converges absolutely since $a>0$.  By Morera's theorem, $F(z)$ is analytic in $\mathbb C$, and as the OP noted
$$
F(z) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
\tag1$$
when $z$ is real. So by the identity theorem, $(1)$ also holds for $z$ complex.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a>0$ and $ \sqrt{a}(x+id)=y.$ Then $\sqrt{a}dx=dy.$ $x\rightarrow \pm\infty\implies y\rightarrow \pm\infty.$ Therefore $$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\exp(-a(x + id)^2)}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\exp( -y^2)}dy/\sqrt{a}=\sqrt{\pi/a}.
$$

Comment: You need more than this.  See J.G.'s answer using a rectangular contour.  To understand why this does not work, consider $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+(x-a)^2}$$.  The value is $\pi$ for real $a$, but the value is $0$ for $a=2i$.  There is a pole at $a=i$, so J.G.'s argument does not work.  But yours (seemingly) does, giving the wrong answer.

Comment: I agree and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since complex numbers appear in this problem, let's solve it with the residue theorem. We'll adapt the ninth proof [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf). Define$$\tau:=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2a}}\left(1+i\right),\,f\left(z\right):=\frac{\exp-az^{2}}{1+e^{-2a\tau z}}$$so$$f\left(z\right)-f\left(z+\tau\right)=f\left(z\right)+e^{a\tau^{2}}f\left(z+\tau\right)=\exp-az^{2}$$and$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp-a\left(z+id\right)^{2}dz=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\left(z+id\right)dz-\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\left(z+id+\tau\right)dz.$$To prove this is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$ regardless of $d$, we use a rectangular contour (see the above link for full details), and the fact that $f$ has a pole at $z=\tau/2$, to show$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\left(z+id\right)dz-\int_{\mathbb{R}}f\left(z+id+\tau\right)dz=2\pi i\operatorname{Res}_{z=\tau/2-id}\frac{\exp-a\left(z+id\right)^{2}}{1+e^{-2a\tau\left(z+id\right)}}=2\pi i\operatorname{Res}_{z=\tau/2}\frac{\exp-az^{2}}{1+e^{-2a\tau z}}=\frac{2\pi i\exp\frac{3a\tau^{2}}{4}}{-2a\tau}.$$This reduces to$$2\pi i\frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{1}{-2a}\sqrt{\frac{2a}{\pi}}\frac{1}{1+i}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}.$$